# How can I loop my output so that all the results in my text file show?

Tags: c++, loops, transactions

EDIT: solved now

So I'm trying to complete a program and I'm pretty sure I'm almost done but I'm missing something I just don't know what it is.

Anyways here's the assignment.

> A bank charges $10 per month plus the following check fees for a
>   commercial checking account:
>
> $0.10 each for fewer than 20 checks $0.08 each for 20-39 checks $0.06
>   each for 40-59 checks $0.04 each for 60 or more checks The bank also
>   charges an extra $15.00 if the balance of the account falls below $400
>   (before any check fees are applied). Write a program named lab2 that
>   inputs for the beginning balance and the number of check written from
>   the transaction file. Compute and display the bank's service fees for
>   the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (transaction = 0; transaction <=5; transaction++)
```

Your for loop is a single line with no `{}`. This results in only the first statement after the loop begin considered as within the loop. Also, put the input statements within the loop.

Replace it with:

```
for (transaction = 0; transaction <=5; transaction++){
   inputFile >> acctBalance;
   inputFile >> numChecks;
   inputFile >> transaction;
   //All your if else statements here

}
return 0;
```

Comment: Just tried that and now the first answer just outputs 6 times.

Comment: inputFile >> transaction; kept it from going through everything so I took it out and now it works. Thanks!